# Show different row and column data in one column using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My tabular data looks like

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(Name VARCHAR(10), VAL INT)

INSERT INTO @Tab 
VALUES ('A', 25), ('B', 30), ('C', 236), ('D', 217), ('E', 19)

SELECT * 
FROM @Tab
```

I want to show my result as:

```
Total:527 (A:25,B:30,C:236,D:217,E:19)
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is called pivoting. There are many examples on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+pivot (Of course I'm assuming something a little more general than the specific scenario you described which returns only a single row. If that's all you want, surely it's just a display issue and SQL is not the best tool for the job?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple method using a sub query with `FOR XML`:

```
SELECT 'Total:' + CAST(SUM(VAL) as varchar(10)) +' ('+ 
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ',' + Name +':'+ CAST(VAL as varchar(10))
    FROM @Tab
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') +')'
 as result
FROM @Tab
```

Results:

```
result
Total:527 (A:25,B:30,C:236,D:217,E:19)
```

[See live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/AMDYL5196)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(VAL) FROM @tab
```

check out the following:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, along with sum I also want the breakup

Answer (score 0):

One method is with a `FOR XML` subquery:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(Name VARCHAR(10), VAL INT);
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('A',25),('B',30),('C',236),('D',217),('E',19);
SELECT 'Total:'
    + CAST(SUM(VAL) AS varchar(10))
    + ' ('
    + STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name + ':' + CAST(VAL AS varchar(10))
    FROM @Tab
    ORDER BY Name
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    + ' )'
FROM @Tab;
```

Comment: Congratulations on 10k reputation

Comment: Thanks, @ZoharPeled.