# Show multiple table's data in one single cell in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show multiple data from tables into one single cell. Please find the script for my tables.

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(code VARCHAR(10), name varchar(20), val1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES ('A', 'Test', 34)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES ('B', 'Test', 6)

DECLARE @Tab1 TABLE(code VARCHAR(10), name varchar(20), val2 INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab1 VALUES ('A','Test', 178)

DECLARE @Tab2 TABLE(code VARCHAR(10), name varchar(20), Total INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab2 VALUES ('A','Test', 180)
INSERT INTO @Tab2 VALUES ('B', 'Test', 10)


DECLARE @Tab3 TABLE(code VARCHAR(10), name varchar(20), val1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab3 VALUES ('A', 'Test1', 56)

DECLARE @Tab4 TABLE(code VARCHAR(10), name varchar(20), val2 INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab4 VALUES ('A','Test1', 87)

DECLARE @Tab5 TABLE(code VARCHAR(10), name varchar(20), Total INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab5 VALUES ('A','Test1', 93)
```

I want to show the data in a cell single cell in the format as below:-

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you a beginner or with fair knowledge of sql? I reckon you just copied those statements from somewhere

Comment: I am beginner, but I need to make this query to work

Comment: We dont answer your school work. We help and correct the errors and issues - so you'll have to do your part first...

Comment: The basic concept is to use `UNION ALL` to stick all those rows together, then use some kind of crosstab to turn all those rows into columns. I suggest you try and learn how to use `UNION ALL`, and post back your effort

Comment: In fact your other questionL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027566/show-different-row-and-column-data-in-one-column-using-sql-query shows you how to do pivotting (another name for crosstab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```
With T (code, [name], val1, val2, total)
AS
(
Select code, [name], val1, 0, 0 from @Tab 
Union
Select code, [name], 0, val2, 0 from @Tab1 
Union
Select code, [name], 0, 0, Total from @Tab2 
Union
Select code, [name], val1, 0, 0 from @Tab3 
Union
Select code, [name], 0, val2, 0 from @Tab4 
Union
Select code, [name], 0, 0, Total from @Tab5 
), 
T2 (code, [name], total, val1, val2)
AS
(
Select code, [name], total = sum(total), val1 = sum(val1), val2 = sum(val2)
from T group by code, [name] 
)
Select code, 
IsNull(Min( case [name] when 'Test' then CONCAT('Total ', total, '(val1:', val1, ',val2:', val2,')')  end ), 'Total 0(val1:0,val2:0)') Test,
IsNull(Min( case [name] when 'Test1' then CONCAT('Total ', total, '(val1:', val1, ',val2:', val2,')') end ), 'Total 0(val1:0,val2:0)') Test1 
from T2 
Group By code
```

Comment: I suggest you use UNION ALL, not UNION, or at least understand the difference